# Get Weights of Neural Network Edges in Flux?

Tags: julia

I'm new to the Flux machine learning package for Julia.  I've got a simple neural network consisting of the following:

- 1 input layer of 4 neurons
- 1 hidden layer of 8 neurons
- 1 output layer of 3 neurons

The architecture is built with this code snippet:

```
layer_1 = Dense(4,8,relu)
output_layer = Dense(8,3)
model = Chain(layer_1, output_layer, softmax)
```

I'd like to view all the edge weights (after training).  In short, the weights for...

- input1 -> hidden1
- input2 -> hidden1
- ...
- hidden8 -> output3

I checked the Flux documentation, but couldn't figure out how to do it. I know I can do sometihng like this:

```
@show( layer_1([1,0,0,0]) )
```

Which in turn will return a vector representing the all the outputs of that layer, and then I can reverse the activation function to find the edge weight to each neuron in that layer, but that seems overly clunky for what should be a simple task.  I must be missing something.

Do you know how I can get all the edge weights (input -> hidden layer, hidden layer -> output)? A code snippet that would work for the above would be ideal.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do

```
@show layer_1.weight
```

to see the weight matrix of the first layer. To see an individual edge, you can index the matrix.

```
# edge from input 2 to hidden 1
@show layer_1.weight[1, 2]
```

EDIT: On older versions of Flux, `layer_1.W` is used for `Dense` layers.

Comment: Your previous answer of layer_1.W was the right one, as it didn't recognize layer_1.weight when I tried it.  If you can update your answer to use/include layer_1.W then I'll happily accept and upvote your answer.

Comment: It was `.W` in old versions of Flux, before being changed to be more consistent with other layers.

Comment: Odd, I had just installed Flux the day before I asked the question, and it was still using .W.